# Error when trying to reinstall package

Tags: apt

I first run `sudo dpkg --remove jenkins` and I get a response :

```
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--remove):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
    jenkins
```

So I then try with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install jenkins` and result is :

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  jenkins
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/68.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 895 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
(Reading database ... 346826 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../jenkins_2.19.1_all.deb ...
Not configured to run standalone
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Not configured to run standalone
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_2.19.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Not configured to run standalone
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_2.19.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone can tell what should I do to fix and update the package ?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` (last command perform a package upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `--force-overwrite` suffix on `dpkg` command, this will overwrite file that causing the error.

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-overwrite (file)
```

In your case, it would be

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_2.19.1_all.deb
```

Make sure everything is fixed by running:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I tried the first command but it;s not working (error is `illegal package name in specifier must start with an alphanumeric character`). So I tried `sudo dpkg -r --force-ovewrite jenkins` but once again I get the message about needing to reinstall package before attemping a removal.

Comment: Anyway did you run second command ? Make sure you write the file too, not just `jenkins`